# What does “pull” in “House Republican leaders pulled legislation to repeal Affordable Care from consideration” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

New York Times (March 24) carries an article under the headline, ”In spectacular defeat for Trump, **push to repeal** Health Law fails,” which is followed with the following paragraph:

> “House Republican leaders, facing a revolt among conservatives and
>   moderates in their ranks, **pulled legislation** to repeal the
>   Affordable Care Act **from consideration** on the House floor Friday
>   afternoon in a spectacular defeat for President Trump on the first
>   legislative showdown of his presidency. House Speaker Paul D. Ryan
>   conceded, “We’re going to be living with Obamacare for the foreseeable
>   future.”

https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/24/us/politics/health-care-affordable-care-act.html?hp&action

Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary provides 15 variety of definitions of the word, “pull,” and I cannot tell which one is appropriate to the interpretation of “pull” used here.

From the context, it appears to me “pull legislation from consideration” means to withdraw the legislation from discussion or voting in contrast to “push to repeal Health Law,” but I’m not sure.

Though it seems a very elementary question, what does “pull” here mean? Is “pull stg from consideration” a popular idiom?

P.S.

Incidentally, I found a paragraph in the concurrent article of NYT appearing under the title, “How the Health Care vote fell apart, step by step” suggesting the usage of pull here as a synonym with “yank.”:

> “Who decided to **pull the bill**? Mr. Trump and the House speaker, Paul
>   D. Ryan, both said it was their decision. “Ryan says that he advised
>   Trump to **pull the bill**,” Julie Hirschfeld Davis, a White House
>   correspondent for The New York Times, wrote in a live analysis.
>   “Interesting, because Trump told us that he had directed Ryan to **yank
>   it**. A lot of blame-shifting going on.”

Comment: The bureaucratic fact is that the vote on the bill was first **placed** onto the schedule, and then was **removed** from the schedule. Since it was not voted on, it did not pass. _Push_ and _pull_ are more active metaphors meaning the same as _place_ and _remove_, but with more aggressive overtones.

Comment: "Pull" in this sense means to *remove*.  More specifically, the bill was removed from the agenda.

Comment: Best synonym which also describes a similar movement: "withdraw".

Comment: I'm guessing it's a variation of **pull out of** sthg, e.g. *he [pulled out](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pull_out) of the race at the last minute*. They **pulled** (out) the proposal  **from** the table of negotiation.

Answer (score 4):

*pulled legislation from the calendar* follows definition 15 from the Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary:

> [transitive] pull something (informal) to cancel an event; to stop
>   showing an advertisement, etc. The gig was pulled at the last moment.

This terminology is common parlance in Washington, D.C., where legislation is "put on the calendar" and "pulled from (or off) the calendar", or taken off the calendar.  "Pulling" the bill suggests more sudden action than simply taking the bill off the calendar.  The House of Representatives has five legislative calendars. 
"Pushing" a bill does not refer to putting it on, or taking it off, the legislative calendar, but rather to the amount of attention that will be given to its passage.

In this particular case, the bill was pulled "from the floor"--the floor of the House of Representatives, where it was apparently already under consideration for a vote.

Answer (score -1):

To push can also mean "to work towards". To say that someone pushed to repeal means they were working towards repealing something.

In the context of pulling legislation, the meaning here is that the House Republican Leaders were using the power of their positions to try to repeal the Affordable Care Act. This use of pull is common in a political context.

"Push" tends to have a **positive** connotation and pulling has a **negative** connotation if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'm afraid your explanation is unclear and possibly a misinterpretation. *Pulled* simply means *withdrawn* here.